# Wrong value in field after marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal primitive structure from C++ to C#, and have following code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace dotNet_part
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Custom custom = new Custom();
            Custom childStruct = new Custom();

            IntPtr ptrToStructure = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(childStruct));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(childStruct, ptrToStructure, true);

            custom.referenceType = ptrToStructure;
            custom.valueType = 44;

            Custom returnedStruct = structureReturn(custom);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrToStructure);

            returnedStruct = (Custom)Marshal.PtrToStructure(returnedStruct.referenceType, typeof(Custom));
            Console.WriteLine(returnedStruct.valueType); // Here 'm receiving 12 instead of 44
        }

        [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        [DllImport("CPlusPlus part.dll")]
        public static extern int foo(Custom param);

        // [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        [DllImport("CPlusPlus part.dll")]
        public static extern Custom structureReturn(Custom param);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Custom
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int valueType;
        public IntPtr referenceType;
    }
}
```

And C++ part:

```
typedef struct Custom CUSTOM;
extern "C"
{
    struct Custom
    {
       int valueType;
       Custom* referenceType;
    } Custom;

    _declspec(dllexport) int foo(CUSTOM param)
    {
      return param.referenceType->valueType;
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) CUSTOM structureReturn(CUSTOM param)
    {
      return param;
    }
}
```

Why I'm receiving 12 instead of 44 in `returnedStruct.valueType`?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the difference of these two values is 32?  If you change 44 to 45, does your result change from 12 to 13?

Comment: The value is still 12, doesn't matter which digit is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors here:

Semantically, you are setting `custom.valueType = 44` but on return of the structure, you are checking `custom.referenceType->valueType`, which should not be 44 -- it should be 0.

The second error is that you are calling `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()` on this pointer (`custom.referenceType`) *before* you unmarshal it!  Which means that you are unmarshalling *unallocated memory* into your `Custom` struct.  At this point, this is undefined behavior, and an answer of 12 is just as valid an outcome as receiving an access violation.

---

To fix the first problem, you either need to check `returnedStruct.valueType` *without* unmarshalling `returnedStruct.referenceType`, or you need to set `childStruct.valueType` to 44 before you marshal it into `ptrToStructure`.

To fix the second problem, you need to reverse the order in which you call `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` and `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()`.

Comment: Thanks, now the solution is obvious.